# VS2015 builds invalid .NET Core code

Tags: visual-studio-2015, .net-core

My environment:

- VS 2015, fresh install with Update 3 (14.0.25431.01)
- Windows 10, latest updates
- Installed .NET Core 1.0.3 SDK (LTS), .NET Core 1.1 SDK (Current) and their runtimes
- VS 2015 Tools Preview 2 (.NET Core)
- No ReSharper

[image]

My dotnet info

```
C:\Users\Ben>dotnet --info
.NET Command Line Tools (1.0.0-preview2-1-003177)

Product Information:
 Version:            1.0.0-preview2-1-003177
 Commit SHA-1 hash:  a2df9c2576

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     Windows
 OS Version:  10.0.14393
 OS Platform: Windows
 RID:         win10-x64
```

[image]

Why VS 2015 thinks, the build was fine here? It cannot be compiled. 
CLI works fine:

```
PM> dotnet build **/project.json
Project VS2015NetCore (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.1) will be compiled because expected outputs are missing
Compiling VS2015NetCore for .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.1
dotnet : C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe compile-csc @C:\Users\Ben\documents\visual studio 
2015\Projects\VS2015NetCore\src\VS2015NetCore\obj\Debug\netcoreapp1.1\dotnet-compile.rsp returned Exit Code 1
At line:1 char:1
+ dotnet build **/project.json
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (C:\Program File...ned Exit Code 1:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

C:\Users\Ben\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\VS2015NetCore\src\VS2015NetCore\Program.cs(7,28): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ThisClassDoesNotExist' could not 
be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Comment: It's giving you a non-0 exit code, and has an error at the bottom.

Comment: @Carcigenicate so you confirm this is a usual behavior? I dont think so.

Comment: I'm not saying this is usual behaviour, I'm saying I don't think it actually compiled. It appears to have thrown an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Re-installed my machine. Now it works.
The usual windows issue solution...

Answer (score 0):

I think here is a general issue. But why? And what?

If I fix the errer, I get a general non-0 error from the CLI:

[image]

Regarding to the dotnet cli repo, error 0x80008081 is caused [by an invalid argument](https://github.com/dotnet/core-setup/blob/eca152525e19a41d489cd5845afa14982653cc0a/src/corehost/error_codes.h).